# What is the number of paths through all squares of a grid from bottom left to top right?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a problem that I set myself when I was at school. Find a formula $f(N,M)$ for the number of paths in an $N\times M$ grid starting at the bottom left, ending at the top right and going through every square once and only once.

I never was able to find a formula for this.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by a path? From what I understand, there's 0 such paths in a 2x2 grid, but I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: When you say "every square" do you mean "every lattice point" ?

Comment: Here's a related (I think) [question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/36368/67014). It looks like it's a hard problem, and no closed-form enumeration is known.

Comment: @futurebird only difference is the function is then $f(N+1,M+1)$ (a)Green correct. (a)pjs36 yes, related to the Hamiltonian problem. Is there any latest research? What is the name of the problem?